# Add a list of contacts to Firebase database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, nosql

I simply want to create a firebase database that holds emails, and contacts for those specific emails. I want to be able to add more contacts for each email, and retrieve the ones I currently have as well.

I have tried many ways but nothing seems to work. Question might be so intuitive for some of you. but I have tried for hours. I always use SQL database; which might be part of the problem. Here is some of my code if it helps.

```
FirebaseDatabase db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
                            DatabaseReference myRef = db.getReference("users");
                            myRef.child(mAuth.getUid()).setValue(email);
```

The ideal result would be:

```
users                                                                                                                                                                                                 
-------{USER EMAIL}                                                                                                                                                                                                            
-------------------------{LIST OF CONTACT CHILDREN}
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about something like this.
If I understand correctly one `user` can have multiple `email` and `phone_number_list`.
You could create new node called `contacts` which you can push `contact object` that contain `user_email` and `phone_number_list`.

```
users
---->contacts
------>firebase_auto_generate_key1
-------->user_email1
-------->phone_number_list
---------->0123456789
---------->0123456789
---------->0123456789
---------->0123456789
------>firebase_auto_generate_key2
-------->user_email2
-------->phone_number_list
---------->0123456789
---------->0123456789
---------->0123456789
---------->0123456789
```

Hope it's help.